# Javascript RegExp lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Problem. I want to replace the word "snippet" in the following string in Javascript

```
<p>This is a <span class="snippet-expansion">snippet<span><p>
```

but i want to preserve the class="snippet-expansion".

Another Case could be

```
<p>This is a snippet within a text<p>
```

The result in the second case should be

```
<p>This is a <span class="highlight-searchterm">snippet</span> within a text<p>
```

Normally, i would do that with a lookbehind in a regular expression, but these are not available in Javascript.

May someone help me?

Comment: jquery solution (which can be written in JS) `$('.snippet-expansion').text().replace('snippet', 'my new text')`

Comment: Thank you, but i wasn't clear enough. I updated the question.

Comment: So you want to wrap a word with a span?

Comment: if so, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery

Answer (score -1):

Works with a lookahead:

```
/snippet(?!-expansion)/
```

REF:
https://regex101.com/r/lH5vA3/1

Comment: To be clear. In my App a User enters some Text in a textfield, for example "sni". I do a search in the Database for all Entries that have sni in their text and pass them back to the frontend. So your case doesn't work for lets say the word "sni".

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to what you're trying to do, but a lookahead should still work if you tweak its matching characters. `s(?!\w|\s|"|-|=)` or `sni(?!\w|\s|"|-|=)`      https://regex101.com/r/lH5vA3/3

Answer (score -1):

try this expression

```
var str='<p>This is a <span class="snippet-expansion">snippet<span><p>';

str.replace(/snippet.*?(\W|\s)+/g,function (val){ if(val.trim().match(/\W+/g) && !val.match(/</g)) return val; return val.replace(/snippet/g,'')  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking for texts between a closing tag `>` and a opening tag `<` should work for your situation.

```js
var str = '<p>This is a <span class="snippet-expansion">snippet<span><p>';
var rep = str.replace(/(>[^<>]*)snippet([^<>]*<)/, "$1foo$2");
document.getElementById("t").value = rep;
document.getElementById("t").value += "\n\n";

var str1 = '<p>This is a snippet within a text<p>';
var rep1 = str1.replace(/(>[^<>]*)snippet([^<>]*<)/, "$1foo$2");
document.getElementById("t").value += rep1;
document.getElementById("t").value += "\n\n";

var str2 = '<p>This is a <span class="highlight-searchterm">snippet</span> within a text<p>';
var rep2 = str2.replace(/(>[^<>]*)snippet([^<>]*<)/, "$1foo$2");
document.getElementById("t").value += rep2;
```

```html
<textarea id="t" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
```