# scroll to searched word from top to bottom with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scroll to **searched word** one by one when I click down button. Please see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch3tan03/ju6xxwvb/2/) for code implemented

```
$('#searchfor').keypress(function(){
  var page = $('#all_text');
  var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
  var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
  var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    
  var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
  page.html(newHtml);
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this intro to angular, using it you can create (amongst many other things) search boxes that search through content and return results on keydown without need to click a button https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo

Answer (score 1):

see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/ju6xxwvb/13/

i used js from hear [Search and Highlight in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery)

and button login is wrriten

```
var find = function(results, type, counter, adjPx, $el) {
    if (results.length > 0) {
        if (type === 'next') {
            if (counter > 0 && results.length == counter) {
                counter = 0;
            }
        } else if (type === 'prev') {
            if (counter < 0) {
                counter = results.length - 1;
            } else if (counter === results.length) {
                counter = counter - 2;
            }
        }
        results.removeClass("active");
        $(results[counter]).addClass("active");
        if ($el) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(results[counter]).offset().top - adjPx
            }, 100);
        } else {
            $el.animate({
                scrollTop: $(results[counter]).offset().top - adjPx
            }, 100);
        }

        counter = (type === 'prev') ? counter - 1 : counter + 1;
    }
    return counter;
};
```