# Search and highlight the result in all the page

Tags: javascript, search, input

I would know if it's possible to highlight a word contained in a form ?

I have a form with a long text written into the input and I want to find a word in this form and only in this form.

I started with this code but it doesn't search into the form.

```
<div id="search_input">
    <form action="" id="form_search">
        <input style="width: 300px" type="text" placeholder="Entrez un mot-clef" id="search">
        <button type="button" id="submit_form" onClick="checkSearch()" value="Submit">Rechercher</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkSearch() {
        var query1 = document.getElementById('search').value;
        window.find(query1);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

**I tried a solution posted in commentary but getting an error :
EDIT :**

```
<div id="search_input">
        <form action="" id="form_search">
            <input style="width: 300px" type="text" placeholder="Entrez un mot-clef" id="search">
            <button type="button" id="submit_form" onClick="checkSearch()" value="Submit">Rechercher</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> 
    function checkSearch() {
        var src_str = $("#fdescription").html();
        var term = document.getElementById('search').value;
        term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
        var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

        src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
        src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

        $("#fdescription").html(src_str);
    }
</script>
```

**The error is** : Uncaught ReferenceError: checkSearch is not defined

Comment: What happens currently? I would do `if( query1.match(/term/i)) { // update query1 }` It looks like your currently only return `true`.

Comment: I know my code is just incomplete, i just found the code on another thread and tried it.. My purpose is to find a text in a textarea form

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery?

Comment: I'm trying but i'm getting an error (Uncaught ReferenceError: checkSearch is not defined). I will edit my code

Comment: Update : With this solution, it doesn't highlight the word contained in the textarea it's only do like this : <mark> Myword </mark>

Comment: Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) to highlight keywords/search terms or custom regular expressions!