# Search within a page function for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working with a page of a wordpress site that is essentially a very long list of names. I'm wondering if there is a bit of HTML that will present a search box on the page next to the list of names that works exactly like CTRL+F. The site owner refuses to learn CTRL+F and also doesn't believe anyone knows how to use it because they don't know how to use it. I searched for something like this but only came up with a lot of really old javascript snippets, none of which seem to work.

Anyone know of any code for this or a plugin?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide an HTML output, so that it will be more easier for us to read. You can check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).