# Highlight results when searching divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div setup like this:

```
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">hello world test 123</div>
  <div class="description">lorem ipsum test test1 testing</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">attack on titan</div>
  <div class="description">fullmetal alchemist</div>
</div>
```

And I allow the user to search the divs with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#search").on("keyup click input", function () {
        var val = jQuery(this).val();
        if (val.length) {
            jQuery(".entry").hide().filter(function () {
                return jQuery('.title, .description',this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
            }).show();
        }
        else {
            jQuery(".entry").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Works great, try [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvq84mhr/2/).

My question is, how can I highlight the search terms? For example, if the user searches for `test`, I want to wrap the text `test` into `<span>` tags.

EDIT: Note that I know how to search/replace text, but I can't seem to make it work properly with my search function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and Highlight in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery)

Comment: I would say this one is a bit different, when using search like this.

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points when it is eligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Optimised solution

After all the issues discussed in comments and trying to optimise the solution so it won't have any lack for eventual bugs, I refactored the code and optimised it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").on("keyup click input", function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    var regExp = new RegExp(val, 'ig');
    var reg = new RegExp('<span class="highlight">(.+)<\/span>', 'ig');
    if (val.length) {
      $(".entry").hide().filter(function() {
        var found = $('.title, .description', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        if (val.length > 3) {
          $('.title, .description', this).each(function(k, v) {
            if ($(v).text().match(regExp)) {
              $(v).html($(v).text().replace(regExp, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>'));
            } else {
              $(v).html($(v).text().replace(reg, '$&'));
            }
          });
        } else {
          $('.title, .description', this).each(function(k, v) {
            $(v).html($(v).text().replace(reg, '$&'));
          });
        }
        return found;
      }).show();
    } else {
      $('.title, .description').each(function(k, v) {
        $(v).html($(v).text().replace(reg, '$&'));
      });
      $(".entry").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">hello world test 123</div>
  <div class="description">lorem ipsum test test1 testing</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">attack on titan</div>
  <div class="description">fullmetal alchemist</div>
</div>
```

It loops over the elements and use a RegExp with a matching group and if the iterated element content matches the Regex replace the matched text with the same content wrapped in a span, otherwise just set the content to its original form.

---

### Original Answer

This is how you should do it:

```
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    if (val.length) {
      $(".entry").hide().filter(function() {
        var found = $('.title, .description', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        var regExp = new RegExp(val, 'ig');
        $('.title, .description', this).each(function(k, v) {
          if ($(v).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            var newHTML = $(v).text().replace(regExp, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
            $(v).html(newHTML);
          }
        });
        return found;
      }).show();
    } else {
      $(".entry").show();
    }
```

You need to loop over the elements and use a RegExp with a matching group and if this element content matches your Regex replace the matched text with the same content wrapped in a span.

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").on("keyup click input", function() {
      var val = jQuery(this).val();
      if (val.length) {
        $(".entry").hide().filter(function() {
            var found = $('.title, .description', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
            var regExp = new RegExp(val, 'ig');
              $('.title, .description', this).each(function(k, v) {
                if ($(v).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                  var newHTML = $(v).text().replace(regExp, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
                  $(v).html(newHTML);
                }
              });
          return found;
        }).show();
    } else {
      $('.title, .description').each(function(k, v) {
        var reg = new RegExp('<span class="highlight">(.+)<\/span>', 'ig');
        var newHTML = $(v).text().replace(reg, '$&');
        $(v).html(newHTML);
      });
      $(".entry").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">hello world test 123</div>
  <div class="description">lorem ipsum test test1 testing</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">attack on titan</div>
  <div class="description">fullmetal alchemist</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

This is a Demo that highlights sentences only if more than 2 letters are typed:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").on("keyup click input", function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    if (val.length) {
      $(".entry").hide().filter(function() {
        var found = $('.title, .description', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        var regExp = new RegExp(val, 'ig');
        if (val.length > 2) {
          $('.title, .description', this).each(function(k, v) {
            if ($(v).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
              var newHTML = $(v).text().replace(regExp, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
              $(v).html(newHTML);
            }
          });
        } else {
          $('.title, .description').each(function(k, v) {
            var reg = new RegExp('<span class="highlight">(.+)<\/span>', 'ig');
            var newHTML = $(v).text().replace(reg, '$&');
            $(v).html(newHTML);
          });
        }
        return found;
      }).show();
    } else {
      $('.title, .description').each(function(k, v) {
        var reg = new RegExp('<span class="highlight">(.+)<\/span>', 'ig');
        var newHTML = $(v).text().replace(reg, '$&');
        $(v).html(newHTML);
      });
      $(".entry").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">hello world test 123</div>
  <div class="description">lorem ipsum test test1 testing</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">attack on titan</div>
  <div class="description">fullmetal alchemist</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is lovely, thanks. Is your approach much different in terms of performance with that of David's?`

Comment: The reason why I ask is because it searches through **tons** of data. So when the user starts typing with the first letter, we have loads of matches, making the browser almost crash. An alternative solution is to only highlight terms if the user has typed 3 characters. Is this possible? The show/hiding of divs should still happen, only the highlighting should take effect only after 3 letters have been typed.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I don't think there's a difference between the two solution, you will be searching for matches along all the elements in all cases. Except that my solution treats the case of empty value in the `else` block, which you can just ommit as it won't cause any trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way you could adjust your answer so that it only highlights the terms *if* 3 letters or more have been typed? If it is 3 or less, it should still show/hide the divs, *but* not highlight it. This is because the span regex replace is simply to slow for massive amounts of data search. Typing 1 letter will replace TONS of letters on the page.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Yes of course we just need to add a test `if (val.length > 2)` with a test to unhighlight them I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, although when there are less than 2 characters, the script is extremely slow with large amounts of data. Please see the code in my original question that show/hide divs and works amazingly with large amounts of data. *That* is the code I want to execute if we have less than 2 characters. And we also need to strip the span tags as well. Am I making any sense? A bit of a puzzle.

Comment: chsdk - ah, I managed to adjust the code in a way where it runs quickly, so your code totally works. It does have one final bug though! Try searching for `test1`. As you can see, it highlights `test` as well, when it should only highlight `test1`. Any fix for this issue?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Ah ok I see it, I will try to find a solution for that.

Comment: Excellent, any luck?

Comment: If you change the `.description` div to `<div class="description">div lorem <span>ipsum</span> test <div>test1</div> testing span</div>` like @HenrikPetterson posted on my answer, your code removes the `span` and `div` tags.

Comment: @chsdk I already resolved that issue which David noted. However, the bug with `test1` is still present. chsdk do you by any chance have a solution for it?

Comment: A potential solution could be to remove all instances of the span before adding the span. Would that work?

Comment: Interesting approach. I ran a few speed tests comparing all the solutions and this one performed the best. Consider using the `<mark>` tag. Noticed the "bug" as well.

Comment: Yes It may be a good solution, but I think the problem comes from the fact that we use ` .indexOf` in the condition, and we aren't treating the case where vl.length is between 0 and 2, I am trying with it.

Comment: @chsdk Other than this issue, this is by far the most complete jQuery solution. I will bounty this 200 points when it's eligible and reward this it. All it's missing is some form of approach that would resolve this particular issue.

Comment: Ok @HenrikPetterson, I am working on an optimised solution for it.

Comment: @chsdk Just checking in to see whether if you got a chance to piece a solution together?

Comment: @GaryWoods Thank you fro the `<mark>` suggestion, it would be a great idea to use it.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson so what do you think about the final solution?

Comment: Sorry chsdk, it is national holiday here in Sweden. Will test this out during the week and respond then. Thank you endlessly for the solution!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson No worries, Enjoy your time.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great, glad to hear this.

Comment: this is removing by <p> <li> or any other tags inside <description>

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`contains(text)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDs-KGt5zUAhWKRI8KHfVuB48QFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjquery%2Fsel_contains.asp&usg=AFQjCNG3T6C3RPTp1Y5T84r1-z41xup-WQ&sig2=Vzn_8qQqbLVHGFDuzWMolQ) instead of `filter()` .initially hide the All div .Then Show only the text contains `div` .And apply the span element to matching letter in the children using [`new RegExp()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNoJbJt5zUAhVGuY8KHUKwCgcQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp&usg=AFQjCNH6oRRKC4pCuWKIT8394k1CoSR_xw&sig2=2MU0INUYhlbSJBAhMNenAQ)

For ignore case sensitive match `ig` in regex and also added code for case insensitive for `contains`

**Updated**  Fix with `.title, .description` on children

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#search").on("input", function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val()
    jQuery(".entry").hide()
    jQuery(".entry:contains(" + val + ")").show()
    jQuery(".entry").each(function() {
      if ($(this).find(".title, .description:contains(" + val + ")")) {
        $(this).find(".title, .description:contains(" + val + ")").html(function() {
          return $(this).text().replace(new RegExp('('+val+')', 'ig'), '<span>$1</span>')
        })
      }
    })
  });

})
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

```css
.entry {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">hello world test 123</div>
  <div class="description">lorem ipsum test test1 testing</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">Attack on titan</div>
  <div class="description">fullmetal alchemist</div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
<div>
  <div class="title">For nested element on titan</div>
  <div>
  <div class="description">fullmetal alchemist nested</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Although I was targeting `.title, .description` and not all children divs. Could you please adjust the code to reflect this? I will reward bounty when eligible.

Comment: Try typing "testing", it still highlights "test" in the `.title`.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson .I was updated. see my updated answer.and limit the children with `.title, .description`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it only seems to match with `.description` now. I think there is a problem with how you use `contain()` there.

Comment: Are your try with latest edit ? 11 min ago.It will fixed the old *contains* error also.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. Your code doesn't detect if the divs are nested. Try for example wrapping the description element into a div like this `<div><div class="description">fullmetal alchemist</div></div>`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson ..Yes i was just target only children from your question.See the edited question .simply change with `find` instead `children` its perform all nested

Comment: bullets styles and links are getting removed, how to overcome this issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('search').onkeyup = userInput;
document.getElementById('search').onclick = userInput;
document.getElementById('search').oninput = userInput;
var allEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.entry');

function userInput () {
    var val = this.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < allEntries.length; i++) {
        var entryElement    = allEntries[i];
        var title           = entryElement.querySelector('.title');
        var description     = entryElement.querySelector('.description');
        var noHtmlSearchStr = '';
        if (title)       noHtmlSearchStr +=       title.innerText;
        if (description) noHtmlSearchStr += description.innerText;
        if (noHtmlSearchStr.length > 0) {
            if (noHtmlSearchStr.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                // Remove existing <b> tags.
                var regexp1 = new RegExp('(<b>|<\/b>)', 'gi');
                if (title)             title.innerHTML =       title.innerHTML.replace(regexp1, '');
                if (description) description.innerHTML = description.innerHTML.replace(regexp1, '');

                if (val.length > 3) {
                    var regexp2 = new RegExp('(' + val + ')(?!>)', 'gi');
                    if (title)             title.innerHTML =       title.innerHTML.replace(regexp2, '<b>$1</b>');
                    if (description) description.innerHTML = description.innerHTML.replace(regexp2, '<b>$1</b>');
                }
                entryElement.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                entryElement.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.entry {
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input id="search">

<div class="entry">
    <div class="title">hello world test 123</div>
    <div class="description">div lorem <span>ipsum</span> test <div>test1</div> testing span</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <div class="title">attack on titan</div>
    <div class="description">fullmetal alchemist</div>
</div>

<div class="entry"></div>

<div class="entry">
    <div class="title">attack on titan</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <div class="description">Let's not go to Camelot, 'tis a silly place</div>
</div>
```

#### Explanation of JS code

1. Bind all events to the `userInput()` function.
2. Get all elements with the `.entry` class and store them in `allEntries`.
3. Get the user's input and store in `val`.
4. Iterate through `allEntries`.
5. Get the text to search on from `title` and `description` and store in `noHtmlSearchStr`.
6. If `val` matches some part of `noHtmlSearchStr` then show the `entryElement`, otherwise hide it.
7. Remove `<b>` tags from `title` and `description`.
8. If the length of the user's search (`val`) is longer than three characters, highlight the matches on the text, otherwise, don't highlight anything.

Comment: This is very nice David. Any chance you could add some minor text describing your approach?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that now @HenrikPetterson

Comment: There is a problem with this one. If you try to type with all caps, it will display the results in all caps and not like the original text. Please let me know if I didn't explain this properly.

Comment: Ok, that is a problem, I'll fix this now.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson The capitalization should be fixed now, can you try it again?

Comment: Works great David. Any particular difference in performance when comparing to chsdk's working solution?

Comment: The reason why I ask is because it searches through **tons** of data. So when the user starts typing with the first letter, we have loads of matches, making the browser almost crash. An alternative solution is to only highlight terms if the user has typed 3 characters. Is this possible? The show/hiding of divs should still happen, only the highlighting should take effect only after 3 letters have been typed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145627/discussion-between-david-and-henrik-petterson).

Comment: It's smart to use `$('.title', this).html($('.title', this).text())` or `title.innerHTML = title.innerText` but it will break the whole layout if the title or the description contains other elements. We just should keep it in mind as it's a little bit **risky** to do it. ^_^

Comment: True @chsdk, but I don't have any evidence that it does have other elements in title and description :)

Comment: @David there are other elements within these divs. Does this take that into account?

Comment: No @HenrikPetterson it doesn't. Is it possible to give an example of these divs in your question so I can update my answer accordingly?

Comment: Absolutely, example: `<div class="description">lorem <span>ipsum</span> test <div>test1</div> testing</div>`

Comment: Ok, thanks for that @HenrikPetterson I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson It's working with tags in the html now. Try searching for "ipsum" or "span".

Comment: This is really inspiring code David, thank you. Is there any way to target the div by class instead of `entryElement.children[0];`... so for example `entryElement.children['.title'];`...

Comment: Certainly @HenrikPetterson. Just use `entryElement.querySelector('.title')`. See my updated answer.

Comment: It gives a `title` is null error if the div is empty unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix that now @HenrikPetterson

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @HenrikPetterson That should be fixed now, can you try it again? (I just added a check like `if (title && description) {`)

Comment: I believe it will not search through entries that has empty div. For example, one entry may have content for `description` but has an empty `title`.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Hmm, good point, it should still search through `.title` even if `.description` is empty. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: I've updated it now @HenrikPetterson please take a look.