# Jquery Search with Highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight live the searched term in the table. I tried wrap and text function also.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.livesearch').on('keyup',function(){
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#searchlist tr').each(function(){
            var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                $(this).show();
                $("#searchlist .thead").show();

                $("#searchlist tr td:contains('" + searchTerm + "')").find(searchTerm).html("<div class='test'>" + searchTerm + "</div>");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show what your code do, your frontend, improved your question to help others

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and Highlight in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery)

Comment: it showes all the <tr>'s in the table with the id searchlist which includes the searchTerm of the input field with the class livesearch. The other <tr>'s hide. – D. Huber 42 mins ago