# How can i display the part of a long text that contains the search term

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-core, search

I found records that contain searched text(in asp.net core razor pages). Now how to display only the part of the text that contains the searched text and not the whole text. like the:

**text:** Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

**search term:** print

**result:**  ... dummy text of the **print**ing and typesetting ...

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this of any use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720984/search-and-highlight-in-jquery? Its a JQuery example that includes a jsfiddle link.

Comment: The main question is that we only show the part where the text is.

Comment: Search for the text. You get the index. Adding the length you know the index of the end of the word. You can now get from 0 to index-1 and then from index + length to end. You could also do that in a loop as long as the text is found. You can then stitch back the pieces adding the bold tag. Give it a shot and post your code.